# Flutter Attach in Android Studio not working

Tags: iphone, flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator

I develop flutter app using the "add-to-app" mode. I tried to use Android Studio to attach to the iPhone Simulator. But when I click the "Flutter Attach" button, there is no response at all and no output on the console.

- I can successfully use terminal `flutter attach` to attach.
- macOS 12.5.1
- Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.5.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (212.5744), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46), io.flutter (70.0.2)
```

How can I find the `flutter attach` error log in Android Studio? Appreciate if you can provide any means to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of Android Studio. Downloaded a archived version of AS solved this problem:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, io.flutter
```